# Sending facebook App invitation using iOS doesn't show app invite dialog for the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am working on Facebook App invitation, If I am already logged in to the Facebook the App dialog appears without any problem but if I am not logged in it doesn't but the control goes to didCompleteWithResults delegate with nil results dict. Please help if possible

```
-(IBAction)InviteFBFriends:(id)sender

{
        if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];        

        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email", @"user_photos"] fromViewController:viewController handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {

                // Process error

            } else if (result.isCancelled) {

                // Handle cancellations

            } else if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]){

                [self InviteFBFriends:nil];

            }

        }];

        return;

    }

    //FOR SENDING INVITATIONS TO FRIENDS

    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];

    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myAppLinkURL];



    FBSDKAppInviteDialog *fBSDKAppInviteDialog = [[FBSDKAppInviteDialog alloc] init];

    fBSDKAppInviteDialog.delegate = self;

    fBSDKAppInviteDialog.content = content;

    [fBSDKAppInviteDialog show];

}



- (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{

    NSLog(@"%@",results);

}

- (void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend performing this method as the following, because there is delay occurs of this block method, besides you should check your response token instead of currentAccessToken

```
-(IBAction)InviteFBFriends:(id)sender {

    if (![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email", @"user_photos"] fromViewController:viewController handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {

                // Process error

            } else if (result.isCancelled) {

                // Handle cancellations

            } else if(result.token){

                [self showInvitationsToFriends];

            }

        }];
    }
}

- (void)showInvitationsToFriends {
    //FOR SENDING INVITATIONS TO FRIENDS

    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];  
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myAppLinkURL];
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self]; 
}
```

Comment: didn't work. No clue why this is happening because control goes to [fBSDKAppInviteDialog show];  and after that without showing the dialog didCompleteWithResults method gets called.

Comment: But if u're logged in, you can see the dialog view ?

Comment: Like u have to press login button 2 times to be able to get the dialog showed up ?

Comment: yes if i am logged in i can see the dialog view and yes if i am not logged in then the login view comes up and after login again invite method gets called and without showing dialog didComplete method gets called

Comment: alternatively u can use your same code just set `fBSDKAppInviteDialog.fromViewController = self;`
as you're saying, view appears but not visible, probably it could be missing `fromViewController`